# varnishlog: multiple TxStatus codes

Tags: varnish

If there a  way to log multiple TxStatus codes with varnishlog ?
Varnishlog man states that there not :)
How could I log multiple codes ?

My command now looks like `varnishlog -c -m TxStatus:301`
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this syntax:

```
{ varnishlog -c -m TxStatus:301 & varnishlog -c -m TxStatus:404 & } > varnish-status.log
```

To view live logs:

```
tail -f varnish-status.log
```

To stop logging:

```
$ ps ax | grep varnishlog
 5009 pts/0    S      0:00 varnishlog -c -m TxStatus:301
 5010 pts/0    S      0:00 varnishlog -c -m TxStatus:404
 5636 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep varnishlog
$ kill 5009
$ kill 5010
```